# How to get black - the python formatter - to work on vscode dev container?

Tags: python, python-black, vscode-devcontainer

I am currently developer in a dev container and I am trying to use black as a formatter for python. However, I failed to make it work. Here is my `.devcontainer.json`

```
{
    "name": "api",
    "dockerComposeFile": ["../docker-compose.yml", "../docker-compose.devcontainer.yml"],
    "service": "api",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace/api",

    "settings": {
        "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/local/lib/python3.8",
        "python.formatting.provider":"black",
        "python.formatting.blackPath":"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/black",
        "python.linting.enabled": true,
        "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
        "python.linting.mypyEnabled":true,
        "editor.insertSpaces": true,
        "editor.tabSize": 4,
        "editor.detectIndentation":false,
        "editor.formatOnSave":true,
    },
    "shutdownAction": "none",
    "extensions": ["ms-python.python", "ms-python.vscode-pylance","ms-azuretools.vscode-docker"],
    //this is port forwarding for the debugger
    "forwardPorts": [8000]
}
```

Comment: One possible solution here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7165

Comment: @Ezra , it is already installed using pip

Answer (score 2):

I updated paths to python and black and rebuilt the container and then there was a little dot on the bell situated to the bottom right. I clicked on it. I cannot remember the message correctly but it asking me to switch to python formatting (something like that) I clicked ok and it worked!

```
{
    "name": "api",
    "dockerComposeFile": ["../docker-compose.yml", "../docker-compose.devcontainer.yml"],
    "service": "api",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace/api",

    "settings": {
        "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/local/bin/python",
        "python.formatting.provider":"black",
        "python.formatting.blackPath":"/usr/local/bin/black",
        "python.linting.enabled": true,
        "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
        "python.linting.mypyEnabled":true,
        "editor.insertSpaces": true,
        "editor.tabSize": 4,
        "editor.detectIndentation":false,
        "editor.formatOnSave":false,
        "[python]": {
            "editor.formatOnSave": true
        },
        "python.testing.pytestPath":"/usr/local/bin/pytest",
        "python.testing.pytestEnabled":true
    },
    "shutdownAction": "none",
    "extensions": ["ms-python.python", "ms-python.vscode-pylance","ms-azuretools.vscode-docker"],
    //this is port forwarding for the debugger
    "forwardPorts": [8000]
}
```